# Is this some kind of browser virus?

Tags: browser, xampp, localhost, root, virus

I run localhost (xampp) in Opera browser, and if I try to watch the code there's unfriendly links everywhere. Is this some browser virus? And what does `:root` do? How can I get rid of that?
Here's a link example:

```
:root a[href^="http://adultgames.xxx/"]
```

[image: Screenshot what i see in browser]

Comment: Thats your directory listing.

Comment: I think OP is referring to the source tab which indeed shows some weird CSS rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing in Opera (and to some degree in Brave) on Fedora 30, but not in Firefox on Ubuntu 19.10. I suspect it is related to the way that the browsers block ads.

If you inspect the same page with another browser (e.g. Firefox or Chrome) you won't see that same code.  Disabling the privacy protection within the browser--Opera's is the blue shield with the checkmark--should make that code that you highlighted go away.  I'm not sure if the change is instantaneous or if you have to refresh the page in order to see the difference.

This is more of a comment than an answer (not enough reputation to comment), so this will probably get buried, ultimately.